# How to pass model data from one controller to another controller spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have my controller-A class like this:

```
@PostMapping("/otp")
public String otpSubmit(@RequestParam("token") String token, HttpSession session, Model model) throws IOException {

Long enrollment = (Long) session.getAttribute("enrollment");
BaseResponse otpResponse = otpRestClient.validateOTP(enrollment, token);
if(otpResponse.getCode().equals("1020")) {
    model.addAttribute("object", otpResponse.getPayload());
    return "redirect:/password";
}

model.addAttribute("errorCode", otpResponse.getCode());
model.addAttribute("errorMessage", otpResponse.getMessage());

return "/otp";
}
```

What I want is simple (I think) pass the `model.addAttribute("object", otpResponse.getPayload());` to controller-B class so I can access that data in the other view.

How can I inject this into controller-B class?.

Comment: You could inject the other controller in this controller and invoke the method passing the model as parameters. Say `@Autowired OtherController otherCtrl`... then inside otpSubmit method `otherCtrl.someMethod(model)`. But I don't know if this is good practice.

Answer (score 3):

By adding redirectAttributes we can pass model data

Here is the Controller one.

```
  public String controlMapping1(
    @ModelAttribute("mapping1Form") final Model model, 
    final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("mapping1Form", model);
return "redirect:mapping2";
```

}

Here is Controller2

```
public String controlMapping2(
    @ModelAttribute("mapping1Form") final Model model) {
model.addAttribute("transformationForm", model);
return "view_name";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can save this "Object o = otpResponse.getPayload()" object in a **global variable** so later you can access it from any controller.