# How to access Model attribute and update view in other method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping("/test/index")
public String index(ModelMap map<----, @PathVariable(value = "language") String language,
        @PathVariable(value = "test") String test, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpSession session) {
.......
}


public void updateView() {
   map.put("key",value);                                
   updateview();
}
```

I want to access and update view in other method,but how to use the ModelMap  as global variable?And how to update the view after map.put()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC - How to get all request params in a map in Spring controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312436/spring-mvc-how-to-get-all-request-params-in-a-map-in-spring-controller)

Comment: By Using RedirectAttributes, see the below link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122495/how-to-pass-model-data-from-one-controller-to-another-controller-spring/49123201#49123201)

Answer (score -1):

As per your current question and given program, i am giving my answer.

1. Create Class level variable for ModelMap
2. Then, generate getter and setter for the same.
3. Now, you can utilize that object where you want.

I hope this answer will give you an idea.